# Как получить значение с противоположным знаком?

Tags: java

Я придумал только один способ:

```
if(x > 0) {
   x -= x*2;
} else
   x -= x*-2;
```

А можно как то без `if-else`, в одну строчку?

Comment: `x -= Math.abs(x*2);`

Comment: Не подходит: допустим x = -5: x = -5 - |-5*2| = -15

Comment: почему не подходит? значения выдает одинаковые, что в вашем примере, что и в примере @entithat

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov Да, вы правы. Исправил пример, теперь если x<0, то будет так: x = -5 + 10;

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov но все равно, в заголовке написано: значение с противоположным знаком, а у него не с противоположным.

Comment: Разве `x -= x*2;` и `x += x*-2;` не одно и тоже?

Comment: @gil9red Мда уж, опять ошибка. Исправил пример.

Comment: Хм.. А `-x` использовать Заратустра не позволяет?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Всё гороздо проще, чем кажется. `x = -x;`, что равносивно `x = -1 * x;`

Comment: Упс, да. Странно, что я об этом не подумал.

Comment: Я даже переприму ответ на ваш, хоть обычно так и не делаю

Answer (score 3):

Условие

```
if (x > 0) {
   x -= x * 2;
} else {
   x -= x * -2;
}
```

можно представить так:

```
x -= x > 0 ? x * 2 : x * -2;
```

или так:

```
x -= x * ((x > 0) ? 2 : -2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Условие

```
if (x > 0) {
   x -= x * 2;
} else {
   x -= x * -2;
}
```

Как насчет `x = -x`?